# 2-way intlist c++ push_front

Tags: c++, list, nodes

I'm writting a 2-way Intlist where every node has a reference to his previous and next node. Everything seems ok but when I use the Push_front() method to add nodes at the begin they have no prev reference.

```
list.push_front(2);
list.push_front(1);
```

2 won't have a reference to 1. Here's my code.

IntNode

```
#ifndef INTNODE_H_
#define INTNODE_H_

class IntNode {
     friend class IntList;
private:
    int data;
    IntNode * prev;
    IntNode * next;
public:
    IntNode(IntNode * previous = 0, IntNode * nextnode = 0):data(0), prev(previous), next(nextnode){};
    IntNode(int data = 0, IntNode * previous = 0, IntNode * nextnode = 0):data(data),prev(previous),next(nextnode){};
    int getData() const {return data;}
    IntNode * getprev() const {return prev;}
    IntNode * getnext() const {return next;}
    void setPrev(IntNode * node){this->prev = node;}
 };
 #endif
```

Intlist.h

```
#ifndef INTLIST_H_
#define INTLIST_H_

#include "IntNode.h"
#include <iostream>
class IntList {
private:
     IntNode * first;
public:
    IntList():first(0){};
    IntList(IntNode * firstnode):first(firstnode){};
    void push_back(int data);
    void push_front(int data);
    void delete_first();
    void delete_last();
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const IntList& list);
    IntNode* getFirst() const {return first;}
};
#endif
```

IntList.cpp

```
#include "IntList.h"

void IntList::push_back(int data){
    if(first){
        IntNode * node = first;
        while(node->next != 0){
             node = node->next;
        }
        node->next = new IntNode(data,node,0);
    }else{
        first = new IntNode(data);
    }
}

void IntList::push_front(int data){
     //first = new IntNode(data,0,first); //prev = 0, no reference when is sec node
     first->setPrev(new IntNode(data,0,first));
}

void IntList::delete_first(){
    if(first){
    if(first->next != 0){
    first = first->next;
    first->setPrev(0);
    }else{first = 0;}
    }
}

void IntList::delete_last(){
    if(first){
    IntNode * temp = first;
    while(temp->next != 0){temp = temp->next;}
    IntNode * node = temp->prev;
    node->next=0;
    delete temp;
    }
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const IntList& list){
    if(list.first){
        IntNode * node = list.first;
        out << node->getData();
        while(node->getnext() !=0){
            node = node->getnext();
            out << node->getData();
         }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you don't create a "first" in `push_front()`.

Comment: Note that you have memleaks in your `delete_*` methods. (and `delete_fist` should not allocate).

Comment: Thx @Jarod42 , is this version better? (ps: do I need to delete the * node? (memleak))

code check original question

Comment: @GNIUS: Better, still a leak in `delete_first`. (using `std::unique_ptr` for `IntNode::next` may solve leak issue for free, but it may be little complex here)

Comment: @Jarod42 : ok, thx. Do I need to delete the IntNode * node  In delete_last?

Comment: @GNIUS: yes (and you did it currently), each `new` should have its `delete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement a Push_front the newly added node becomes the first, and this does not happen in your code.

This should work.

```
void IntList::push_front(int data)
{
    IntNode *newfirst = new IntNode(data, 0, first);
    if (first) {
        first->setPrev(newFirst);
    }
    first = newFirst;
}
```

Comment: I tried that one to, but didn't help. Maybe it's just another fault in my code. Thanks

Comment: Thx, i found the answer. He crashes when there's no first yet (with the 1st node added) this is the correct code : 

if(first){
        IntNode * newfirst = new IntNode(data,0,first) ;
        first->setPrev(newfirst);
        first = newfirst;
        }else{
        first = new IntNode(data,0,0);
        }